# Eclipse drools plugin cannot edit constraints

Tags: java, eclipse, drools, bpmn

I am trying to edit constrains on BPMN Eclipse plugin editor BUT I can't open the popup of editing the constraint (link) as shown in this [tutorial](https://nheron.gitbooks.io/droolsonboarding/content/gettingStarted/lesson_4__ruleflow.html). 
I tried double click, right click and viewing properties tab but not worked.
Using: Eclipse Mars, drools plogin 6.4.0.Final. Below image from tutorial. Anyone has idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer.
Example is below:

[image]

and select constraint field then choose [...] button so you will poped up below window, then you can continue:

[image]